# Can I pass parameter values to dynamically compile and generate a winform application?

Tags: c#

The back end requirement is that I'd like to assign a unique ID to each winform application and give it to the specific agent, so that when the agent helps promote my application, the end users would use an application that has the agent ID embedded inside and I can get that ID from any request from that specific winform application.

Comment: app.config seems to me like a good place for this.

Comment: thanks. i thought about this too. but i don't want the file to be visible and potentially editable by end users.

Comment: You can create a hash inside the winforms application based on the unique machine key, username and some other prorperties